# How to catch an exception thrown in another Powershell script?

Tags: exception, powershell-2.0

I have a two Powershell scripts; main.ps1 and sub.ps1. main.ps1 calls sub.ps1. Sometimes sub.ps1 throws an exception. Is it  possible to catch the exception thrown by sub.ps1 from main.ps1 ?

Example main.ps1:

```
try{. .\sub.ps1;}
catch
{}
finally
{}
```

Example sub.ps1:

```
throw new-object System.ApplicationException "I am an exception";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
try {
    sub.ps1
}
catch {
    Write-Warning "Caught: $_"
}
finally {
    Write-Host "Done"
}
```

Use `help about_Try_Catch_Finally` for more details.
Yet another way is to use `trap`, see `help about_trap`. If you have some C# or C++ background then I would recommend to use Try_Catch_Finally approach (but it also depends on what exactly you do).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it has not solved the problem. I use dot sourcing to call the script. Could it be the problem ?

Comment: It works for me with dot sourcing or not. The problem is elsewhere then, more information might help. What errors exactly do you get?

Comment: Are you sure that sub.ps1 throws an *exception* and not just writes an *error*? Try this `$ErrorActionPreference = 'stop'` before call of sub.ps1

Comment: I found the problem. In my catch statement, there was nothing written to the output to indicate the exception was catched. 

Your solution definitely works.

Thanks.

Comment: Still works for me with your exception.. What error do you get when you run main.ps1? Or what exactly happens? Nothing at all? Can you take a look at your $Error list?

Comment: I am glad that you solved the problem. Just a note: even if you swallow exception (empty catch block) errors are still added to the $Error list and can be seen (unless something explicitly removes them from there).